# Loop not breaking after loop restarts

Tags: while-loop, python-3.8

When an input is put into the while loop that is in-valid, it restarts the function. However, the loop wont't break after any input after the functions restarts.

here's the program:

```
def main():
    type_of_user = input("Are you a student? ")
    while True:
        if type_of_user.lower() == "y":
            print("Your price is $3.50/m")
            break
        elif type_of_user.lower() == "n":
            print("Your price is $5.00/m")
            break
        else:
            print("Not valid")
            main()
```

If you input y the first time it works and the loop breaks.

```
  Are you a student? y
  Your price is $3.50/m
```

if you input n the first time it works and the loop breaks:

```
  Are you a student? n 
  Your price is $5.00/m
```

if you enter an invalid input the first time, the loop never breaks, even if the input is y or n:

```
Are you a student? b
Not valid
#now loop continues
Are you a student? y
Your price is $3.50/m
Not valid   #also prints not valid after valid inputs
Are you a student? n 
Your price is $5.00/m
Not valid
Are you a student?
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `main()` inside your `else` clause.  If you enter an invalid response once, then a valid response, the `break` will break out of the loop in the second call to the function, but the loop in the first call will still be running.

Instead, you should ask the question inside the loop, to avoid the recursive call:

```
def main():
    while True:
        type_of_user = input("Are you a student? ")
        if type_of_user.lower() == "y":
            print("Your price is $3.50/m")
            break
        elif type_of_user.lower() == "n":
            print("Your price is $5.00/m")
            break
        else:
            print("Not valid")
```